# Using regular expressions to split one column into multiple columns

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table and some data:

```
-- Table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myTable` (
  `myColumn` varchar(32) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- Data
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`myColumn`) VALUES
('AAA BBB CCC'),
('AA BB CCCC'),
('BBB CC AAAA'),
('C AAA BBB'),
('CCC AA BBB');
```

I would like to run a `SELECT` query that return 3 columns.

The columns should be called `A`, `B`, and `C`.

The result should look something like:

```
+------+-----+------+
| A    | B   | C    |
+------+-----+------+
| AAA  | BBB | CCC  |
| AA   | BB  | CCCC |
| AAAA | BBB | CC   |
| AAA  | BBB | C    |
| AA   | BBB | CCC  |
+------+-----+------+
```

I have three regular expressions which, by using them all, can match all data:

```
^([A]+) ([B]+) ([C]+)$
^([B]+) ([C]+) ([A]+)$
^([C]+) ([A]+) ([B]+)$
```

Is it possible to use these regular expressions to produce such a result?

If so, would appreciate an example, even if only for a subset of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update — September 2021**

This is now possible.

[MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) as well as [MariaDB 10.0.5](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_substr/) introduced support for the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function, which applies a regex on an input string, and returns the matching part (or NULL if there was no match). This is much more powerful and flexible that the former `SUBSTRING_INDEX` approach.

Using this function in MySQL, the original problem can be resolved with the following query:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(myColumn, '[A]+') AS `A`, 
       regexp_substr(myColumn, '[B]+') AS `B`,
       regexp_substr(myColumn, '[C]+') AS `C`
  FROM ...
```

*Side note: Capturing Nth matching occurence*

MySQL's `REGEXP_SUBSTR` accepts a third argument, indicating the occurence number to be returned. For example, to return the third word in the input string, one could write: `regexp_substr(myColumn, '[a-z]+', 3)`. This is however not supported by MariaDB.

The same can be achieved using `REGEXP_REPLACE` by expanding the original pattern to a sequence of capture groups. For example, one could use the following regex to capture the third word of the input string:

```
regexp_replace(myColumn, '^([a-z]+) ([a-z]+) ([a-z]+).*$', '\\3')
```

**Original answer**

This can't be done using regexes in MySQL. Unfortunately, MySQL support regexes only as a boolean condition (notably in where clauses), but not to extract nor alter the content of a string.

You may however achieve what you described entirely from a MySQL query, using [substring_index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index). Here is an example usage for your scenario.

```
SELECT substring_index(substring_index(myColumn, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) AS `A`, 
       substring_index(substring_index(myColumn, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) AS `B`,
       substring_index(                myColumn         , ' ', -1) AS `C`
  FROM ...
```

Alternatively, if you must absolutely use regexes, then you might pipe MySQL's output to some regex engine. Ask me if you need more info about this strategy.